# Get the _id of inserted document in Mongo database in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I use NodeJS to insert documents in MongoDB. Using `collection.insert` I can insert a document into database like in this code:

```
// ...
collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(err){
   if (err) return;
   // Object inserted successfully.
   var objectId; // = ???
});
// ...
```

How can I get the `_id` of inserted object?

Is there any way to get the `_id` without getting latest object inserted `_id`?

Supposing that in same time a lot of people access the database, I can't be sure that the latest id is the id of object inserted.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is a second parameter for the callback for `collection.insert` that will return the doc or docs inserted, which should have _ids.

Try:

```
collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(err,docsInserted){
    console.log(docsInserted);
});
```

and check the console to see what I mean.

Comment: Callback actually returns array of documents inserted. So, if you have inserted a single document then you can access the inserted record as below.

collection.insert({name:"David", title:"About MongoDB"}, function(err, records){
  console.log("Record added as "+records[0]._id);
});

Ref: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Comment: The Callbacks API has changed: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~WriteOpResult

Comment: link does not lead anywhere useful

Comment: I don't know if this is general or only works in meteor, but when you call collection.insert(object), it returns the id of the inserted object right away.

Comment: docsInserted  does not return an _id for me. it returns for me {
  "ok": 1,
  "n": 1,
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "6361004504208375809",
    "t": 5
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000005"
}

Comment: @davidhadas - I removed the link - runnable was sold to Mulesoft and they took down their product

Comment: ✅ In my case, the right answer was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204838/6195123 Just getting the element with await [operation], then like this `result.insertedId.toString()`, and done ✅

Answer (score 101):

A shorter way than using second parameter for the callback of `collection.insert` would be using `objectToInsert._id` that returns the `_id` (inside of the callback function, supposing it was a successful operation).

The Mongo driver for NodeJS appends the `_id` field to the original object reference, so it's easy to get the inserted id using the original object:

```
collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(err){
   if (err) return;
   // Object inserted successfully.
   var objectId = objectToInsert._id; // this will return the id of object inserted
});
```

Comment: Very insightful thank you. Couldn't find this information anywhere else since the change in callback parameters.

Comment: @BradHein You're welcome! Probably the MongoDB driver modifies the object reference, so it gets modified here too. :)

Comment: Your code is wrong, where you say var objectId = objectToInsert._id; you meant to say var objectId = objectInserted._id;

Comment: @AndyLorenz What is `objectInserted`? I guess you're missing exactly the point of this answer: the Mongo driver appends the `_id` field to the original object. I edited the answer to use `objectToInsert` everywhere. Hope the things are clearer now. :)

Comment: Well you have edited your reference to "objectInserted" out of your answer, I was only commenting on your own mistake. The point you say I have missed is exactly what your answer should make explicit - and therefore I have submitted an edit of your answer for peer review (so that it spells out very clearly how to achieve a solution in this way). regards

Comment: @AndyLorenz I saw your edit suggestion -- this is not a Meteor behavior but it's done by MongoDB driver (I guess!). Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: whoops, if I'd said Meteor then I of course meant Mongo !  But I see you've edited your answer again and yes it looks much more useful now - and so I've upvoted it :)

Comment: @AndyLorenz Yeah... Everybody loves upvotes. I gave you some as well. :)

Comment: NOTE: `insert()` is deprecated. Use `insertOne()` instead

Comment: @evilReiko Interesting. Source?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I can't seem to find it in the official documentation, but at least that's what my IDE told me, also, I found this which seems to enhance that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36794912/134824

Comment: To get the inserted ID as a string use objectId.toString()

Answer (score 22):

As ktretyak said, to get inserted document's ID best way is to use insertedId property on result object. In my case result._id didn't work so I had to use following:

```
db.collection("collection-name")
  .insertOne(document)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.insertedId);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error
  });
```

It's the same thing if you use callbacks.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to take "_id" use simpley

```
result.insertedId.toString()
```

// toString will convert from hex

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Yea, there must have been a version change since the other answers don't mention `result.insertedId` is an `ObjectID` type object. `.toString()` will convert this object into a real UUID.

Answer (score 12):

I actually did a console.log() for the second parameter in the callback function for insert. There is actually a lot of information returned apart from the inserted object itself. So the code below explains how you can access it's id.

```
collection.insert(objToInsert, function (err, result){
    if(err)console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log(result["ops"][0]["_id"]);
        // The above statement will output the id of the 
        // inserted object
       }
});
```

Comment: This outputs an `ObjectID {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Buffer(12)}`. How can i use it to get the actual id that is in the database?... 
Found the answer in another comment: Use `result.insertedId.toString() `

Answer (score 9):

You could use **async functions** to get _id field automatically without manipulating data object:

```
async function save() {
  const data = {
    name: "John"
  }

  await db.collection('users').insertOne(data)

  return data
}
```

Returns (`data` object):

> {
>     _id: '5dbff150b407cc129ab571ca',
>     name: 'John',
> }

Comment: Best answer not using the callbacks! Thanks!

Comment: should be the accepted answer, straight to the point with await

Comment: How to the function add `_id` as new attribute to a `const` object wothout throws?

Comment: @e-info128 It's basic JavaScript. If a constant variable is an object, you can change its properties. This is valid: `data._id = "test";` even though `data` variable is a constant.

Answer (score 8):

Mongo sends the complete document as a callbackobject so you can simply get it from there only.

for example

```
collection.save(function(err,room){
  var newRoomId = room._id;
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Now you can use [insertOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne) method and in promise's result.insertedId

Comment: Could you provide a code example? Where does this result object come from?

Comment: @JSideris, as you can see in the specification method [insertOne()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne), this method accepts three parameters `(doc, options, callback)`. The third parameter - a callback, [which takes two parameters](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpCallback) `(error, result)`. And `result` - this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

@JSideris, sample code for getting insertedId.

```
db.collection(COLLECTION).insertOne(data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) 
      return err;
    else 
      return result.insertedId;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other responses, you can grab the variable using async await, es6+ features.

```js
const insertData = async (data) => {

  const { ops } = await db.collection('collection').insertOne(data)
  console.log(ops[0]._id)
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in Javascript :

```
  let insert = await messageDB.insertOne({
  });
  console.log(insert.insertedId);
```

sooo easy!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in async function :

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const db = require(path.join(__dirname, '../database/config')).db;
const router = express.Router()

// Create.R.U.D
router.post('/new-order', async function (req, res, next) {

    // security check
    if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
        res.status(404).send({
            msg: "Error",
            code: 404
        });
        return;
    }

    try {

        // operations
        let orderNumber = await db.collection('orders').countDocuments()
        let number = orderNumber + 1
        let order = {
            number: number,
            customer: req.body.customer,
            products: req.body.products,
            totalProducts: req.body.totalProducts,
            totalCost: req.body.totalCost,
            type: req.body.type,
            time: req.body.time,
            date: req.body.date,
            timeStamp: Date.now(),

        }

        if (req.body.direction) {
            order.direction = req.body.direction
        }

        if (req.body.specialRequests) {
            order.specialRequests = req.body.specialRequests
        }

        // Here newOrder will store some informations in result of this process.
        // You can find the inserted id and some informations there too.
        
        let newOrder = await db.collection('orders').insertOne({...order})

        if (newOrder) {

            // MARK: Server response
            res.status(201).send({
                msg: `Order N°${number} created : id[${newOrder.insertedId}]`,
                code: 201
            });

        } else {

            // MARK: Server response
            res.status(404).send({
                msg: `Order N°${number} not created`,
                code: 404
            });

        }

    } catch (e) {
        print(e)
        return
    }

})

// C.Read.U.D


// C.R.Update.D


// C.R.U.Delete



module.exports = router;
```