# mongoose, getting object's id after using collection.insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get the object id after adding it to the db (using `collection.insert`)

```
mongoose.model('Persons').collection.insert(person, function(err, newPerson) {
 console.log('lets see you', newPerson);
});
```

and from the console I'm getting only `result: { ok: 1, n: 1 }` in stand of the new obj, any ideas how can I rich to the new object ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use save() here

```
var Persons = mongoose.model('Persons');
var personJSON = {
  ..... // persons schema values you want to insert
};
var person = new Persons(personJSON);
var result = yield person.save();
```

result variable will contain all the fields you inserted along with _id

Comment: and with `collection.insert` its possible ?

Comment: @greW similar question may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs