# How to get parent object from child's post save callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have homeworks array in class model. When new homework added I send message via socket in post save callback. How can I access parent _id from that callback?

Comment: possible duplicate? link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs

Comment: @livepo no, I have only child object passed like an argument in this callback.

Comment: @livepo it isn't callback passed to save function but post save hook declared in schema with schema.post('save', callback);