# Get the inserted document(s) in MongoDB 3.0

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Seems like [`db.collection.insert()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.insert) <strike>used to [accept a callback function as last argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14481798/1364424) but the api has since changed and now it</strike> just returns a [`writeResult`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#writeresults-insert) object reporting only the number of documents inserted..

How can I get the actual documents just inserted (or at least their _ids)?

### Update

Yes, I'm running my script in the [`mongo` shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) and I realize now the other stack overflow question I linked to above is about the node.js driver which has a different API (while it's also javascript and looks similar) and so:

1. The `mongo` shell has never reported the details of inserted doc(s) and does not do so still (correct me if I'm wrong)
2. There's an accepted answer below showing how to achieve this in Python

Comment: Are you talking about the shell? I think you are talking about the shell but looking at a question using the `nodejs` driver. The shell has never done such a thing. But is does now if you know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell never returns the "_id" as such, but if you are using any scripting language this is how it can be done in python:

```
insert_result = db.collection.insert({"_id":10, "key":"value"})
```

The insert_result will contain the "_id" of the recently inserted document ie. 10