# How can i copy the complete huge text file data to Mongo DB using Ruby at a time?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, text, cucumber

```
accountInsert = @collection.insert_one({"Acctnum" =>   })
```

using this i am able push the record from text file to mongo one by one but it is taking huge time. Is there any way to push the complete file at a time ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `insert()` or `insertMany()` function

[What's the difference between insert(), insertOne() and insertMany() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792649/whats-the-difference-between-insert-insertone-and-insertmany-method)