# Mongodb insert callback never called

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This question is a followup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs) and I figured it was better to ask a new question than to post a comment and necropost.

(TL;DR they give a solution to get the _id when a collection is inserted)

I've tried with a .js bash script or in console it doesn't seem to work to do :

```
var latest;
db.collec.insert({test:"yes"},function(err,newDoc){
    latest = newDoc[0]._id;
 });
```

The variable doesn't change. In console the command returns `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })` but lastest is still void, and in js it has the same value as before.

Is there a way to get the id without Node.js ? Should I switch to Node.js ?

---

My bash script is really just `mongo --eval '<my whole javascript>'`

Comment: You want to do it in MongoDB shell you mean?

Comment: Make sure you use the "latest" variable inside the "db.collec.insert" callback scope. If you use "latest" outside of this scope, it probably will be executed before the insertion.

Comment: @hyades I'm not sure of the terminology I'm using. By "mongo console" I mean when you type `mongo` in bash and then you have a javascript environment with `>`. Other program call that a console, geth for example.

Comment: _By "mongo console" I mean when you type mongo in bash and then you have a javascript environment with >._ Then yes you mean using the mongodb console/shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one piece in your expression.

```
var latest;
db.collec.insert({test:"yes"},function(err,newDoc){
    latest = newDoc.ops[0]._id;
});
```

`newDoc` contains the entire response from mongo.

`newDoc.ops` contains an array of the inserted row(s).

`newDoc.insertedIds` contains an array of the ID's of the inserted row(s).

An alternative solution would be:

```
var latest;
db.collec.insert({test:"yes"},function(err,newDoc){
    latest = newDoc.insertedIds[0];
});
```

You can get the data without using Node.js.  You can use the Mongodb shell.  From the command prompt on the system running Mongo type `mongo` to get to the interactive shell.  Once there, run Mongo commands:

```
> show dbs  //will list all databases
> use dbName  //will use database called dbName
> show collections  //will list all collections within the current database
> db.col.find({test: 'yes'});  //will retrieve document from collection named col where 'test' = 'yes'
```

Entire working JavaScript file:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongodb.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDb', function(err, db){
   var collection = db.collection('collec');
   collection.insert({'test': 'yes'}, function(err, results){
      console.log(results.ops[0]._id);
      db.close();
   });
});
```

This can be used to query by the `_id` directly.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

mongodb.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDb', function(err, db){
   var collection = db.collection('collec');
   var id = ObjectId('583346693b3b904546ca175d');
   collection.find({'_id': id}).toArray(function(err, results){
      console.log(results);
      db.close();
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work for what I think is another reason. Callback is simply not called. I tried writing `latest = "0"` in it, or just **anything** like test prints or things like that, but nothing in the callback function gets done. I've also tried stuff like `if(err) ... else ...` but still nothing written between the accolades is done. Is it because I run the script from bash ? (`bash mongoscript.js "arg1"`)

Comment: If I put the rest of my script in callback and run `bash mongoscript.js "arg" &`, it waits forever... And googling "*mongodb insert callback*" returns almost only results about node.js, I'm starting to think I don't have any options there...

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, based on your description I assumed you were using the mongo shell or a javascript app.  Now it seems like you are using a bash script.  Please add your bash script to the question.

Comment: It's really basic. It's literally just `mongo --eval '<my javascript>'`

Comment: And again, if bash script isn't a good way to do it I'd be happy to know other ways !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, If you are going to run this script more than once or do something more than insert a simple document, I would recommend using a JavaScript file running from Node.js.  You can run JavaScript files with `mongo dbname 'filename.js'`, but `console.log()` does not output as expected.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, I added a complete working JavaScript file to the answer.  This will work with `node filename.js`.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried switching to nodejs but I'm struggling to do the basic stuff I do easily with javascript. And yes, the script is meant to be used a lot. I'll try your solution when I'm back to work, I can't do anything from home.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! Can I ask you what  `ops` does ? I can't really use it fully if I don't understand it. I'm also curious why this returns directly something like `582dde4643135xxxxx`, but if in mongo shell I type `db.collec.find()[0]._id`, I get `ObjectId("582dcxxxxxx")`, not directly the number. Is it the same ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, The response from Mongo to Node.js is a JSON object.  The `ops` value is an array that typically contains the result of a query.  The Mongo `_id` itself is of type ObjectId.  In Mongo shell will convert the value for you from string to Objectid when using it in a query.  In Node,js, you have to create an ObjectId before passing it to Mongo.  I'll add a sample to my answer above.  For more information about Mongo/Node.js go [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, If this is helpful, consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Yes of course, I tried your answer then I fell into a series of problems I had to solve to make the whole thing work and it took me some time and made me forget, but it was my goal to mark it as accepted :) Thanks a lot again.

Comment: By the way, there are a number of other mongodb command, that don't always return rows (ops sometimes returns an error). Where did you find this information ? It seems I missed the doc about it, and it would be nice to have the info for every command.

Comment: I put this link in one of my posts, but I think made it too subtle... https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/.  From there choose the API for the version of MongoDB you are running.