# return object id after save mongodb, can you help me?

Tags: mongodb, express

how to retrieve objectid after save ? iam using mongodb, expressjs. i not use mongoose, can you help me

```
var dataID = "";
mongo.connect(urlMongo,function(err,db){
    assert.equal(null,err);

    db.collection('item').insertOne(item,function(){
        assert.equal(null,err);
    });
});

res.send(dataID);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the \_id of inserted document in Mongo database in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

From the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/):

InsertOne returns a document containing:

- A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was disabled.
- A field insertedId with the _id value of the inserted document.

The following code works for me:

```
db.collection('item').insertOne(itemToInsert,(err, item) => console.log(item.insertedId))
```

Comment: Or just create the _id yourself:
_id: new mongo.ObjectID();

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataID = "";
mongo.connect(urlMongo,function(err,db){
    assert.equal(null,err);

    db.collection('item').insertOne(item,function(err, res){
        dataID = res.ops[0]._id
        assert.equal(null,err);
    });
});

res.send(dataID);
```

Use res.ops[0]._id to get the ID of inserted object