# How to get id back, after posting data to mongoDb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using node.js, angularjs, & mongoDb. 
I am creating a product upload page.
It is divided into  2 parts:

1. **Data page**: This part will contain, textfields & dropdowns.
2. **Image Upload page**: This part will have image upload control.

So I thought to create 2 forms in same page, from first page i will post text data to mongoDb, return **product_id** of the newly created product, and then upload images with returned **product_id**.

I have developed restFul API to post product `api/products/create-product`.

**Product model** :

```
{
productName:{type: String},
productPrice:{type: Number}
}
```

**Image model**:

```
{
productId:{type: String},
imagePaths:[{type: Array}]
}
```

**Product Controller(Angular):**

```
$scope.newProduct = function(){
      var formData = new FormData;
      for(key in $scope.product){
        formData.append(key, $scope.product[key]);
      } 
  //getting the files
  var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
  formData.append('image', file);

  //Post data
  $http.post('http://localhost:3000/products/api/new-product',formData,{
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  }).then(function(res){
    $scope.item = res.data;

  });
}
```

**Angular front-end**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="product.productName" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" >
<button type="submit" ng-click="newProduct()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
```

**POST API**

```
router.post('/api/new-product',upload.any(),function(req, res, next){

  var pro = req.body;
  if(req.files){
    req.files.forEach(function(file){

      var filename = (new Date()).valueOf() + '-' + file.originalname;
      fs.rename(file.path,'public/images/'+ filename, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        //Save to mongoose

      var product = new Products({
          productName: req.body.productName
         });
          product.save(function(err, result){
          if(err){ throw err}
            res.json(result);
        });



      });
    });
  }
});
```

**Questions**:

1. Am I doing this correct way, or there is another better way for doing this?
2. If this is correct way, then how can I post get posted **product_id**, in order to post images?

   Thanks.

Comment: You also can just generate a new id __before__ the insert, in your client code. This way, you don't need to get the new id, you know it already.

Comment: How can I create `productId` prior pushing data to mongoDb?

Comment: No idea about how to do this in node.js. I'm sure, the documentation has it covered.

Comment: I believe, when you insert new document in your collection, at that very moment mondoDb creates a unique id for your entry.So, prior pushing anything into database we cannot create unique key.

Comment: that's default behaviour, yes. But the generation scheme for mongo's object ids gives pretty good guarantees that you can generate it on the client and it will still be unique.

Comment: Yes, that will be unique, but can we generate 12 byte mongodb key on client side?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure you can. Have you looked in the documentation of node.js mongodb api?

Comment: random key will be generated using randomstring module you can generate it after the data entered into database. using randomstring you can generate key like this randomstring.generate({length:12,charstet:'alphabetic'});   charset is your wish it may be either aplhabetic,numeric ,abc,and pattern you can follow

Comment: yes, @SyedAyeshaBebe : only after saving data we can generate `id's` in mongodb, prior posting data i believe we cannot generate id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my config file which makes connection with mongodb. This is `config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    'secretKey': '12345-67890-09876-54321',
    'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/image'
}
```

Here is my `schema's`. I created two collections one is `products` and another is `images`. Keep these two schemas in `models` folder. Here is my product schema I named it as `product.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

productName:{type: String},
productPrice:{type: Number}

});
module.exports  = mongoose.model("product", nameSchema);
```

Here is my images schema I named it as `image.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var imageSchema = new Schema({
imagepath:{
    type:String,
    required:true
}
});
var nameSchema = new Schema({
 productId:{type: String},
imagePaths:[imageSchema]
});
module.exports  = mongoose.model("image", nameSchema);
```

Here is `html` file keep this file in `views` folder. I named it as `index.html`

```
<form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/api/file"
      method="post"
>
 <input type="file" name="userFile"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">

</form>
```

Next here is routes file keep this file in `routes` folder and named it as `route.js`.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Image = require('../models/image');
var Product = require('../models/product');
var app = express();
var Router = express.Router();
Router.use(bodyParser.json());

Router.get('/product',function(req,res){
 Product.find({}, function (err, product) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(product);
    });
})  
Router.post('/productData',function(req, res, next){
    Product.create(req.body, function (err, product) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Product Data created!');
        var id = product._id;

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the product data with id: ' + id);
    });    
})
Router.put('/postingImage/:Id',function(req,res,next){
 Image.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.Id, {
        $set: req.body
    }, {
        new: true
    }, function (err, batch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(batch);
    });
})

Router.get('/image',function(req,res){
 Image.find({}, function (err, img) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(img);
    });
})  
    module.exports = Router;
```

Here is server code named it as `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Image = require('./models/image');
var Product = require('./models/product');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var rand;
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

var config = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        //callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
                //callback(null, file.originalname)
        rand=Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);

        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + rand);

    }

})
var upload = multer({
        storage: storage});
app.get('/api/file',function(req,res){
res.sendFile('E:/syed ayesha/nodejs/nodejs/uploads/db/views/index.html');
});

app.post('/api/file',upload.single('userFile'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.file.path);

    Image.create({imagePaths:[{imagepath:req.file.path}]},function(err,img){

            if (err) throw err;
     console.log(img);
        console.log('Path created!');
        var id = img._id;

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the image path with id: ' + id);
    });    
})

var route = require('./routes/route');
app.use('/route',route);
    app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server listening on 3000");
});
```

Run the server as `node app.js`

Here are my `API's` to post product details & post image path in mongodb

1. Use `POST` method for posting product details use `http://localhost:3000/route/productData`. Post the data through body like

{
    "productName":"cream",
    "productPrice":88
}

2. Use `GET` method for getting the product detials from mongodb for that use `http://localhost:3000/route/product`
3. Now open browser and type `http://localhost:3000/api/file` then choose a file to upload click on submit button then you will get document Id in response.Just make a note of this Id .You will use this I for posting productId in Image schema.
4. When you want to see the image path details from mongodb use `GET` method and use `http://localhost:3000/route/image`.
5. And now you can add productId in image schema using the document Id that you got in previous. For this use `PUT` method and use `http://localhost:3000/route/postingImage/59ae2f9195730f1e00be7509` here I just I gave my document Id .You need to put your document Id there. And send the productId through body like this

   {
       "productId":"59a6ac68a87d9f102c4496b8"
   }

After this you will the response as [image]

You can che in mongodb also .

1. `use image`
2. `show collections`
3. `db.images.find().pretty();`
4. `db.product.find().pretty();`
   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped.

Comment: Do you know any online editor for practicing MEAN stack?

Comment: I am glad it helps...If you have any queries ask me I try to solve it....

Comment: sure, that really helped :)

Comment: I didn't use any online editors I just use postman tool for executing applications....

Comment: Hi Ayesha, I was able to store image-path to database, but now how can I display stored image using `Angular Js`?

Comment: But that will upload file data to mongo db.I am just storing image filePaths to database, and want to `GET` imagePath from database and display it using `angular Js`

Answer (score 2):

5sec into google (didn't test it):

```
collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(err){
   if (err) return;

   // Object inserted successfully.
   var objectId = objectToInsert._id; // this will return the id of object inserted
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You can post the product data using this code

```
app.post('/productData',function(req, res, next){
    Product.create(req.body, function (err, product) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Product Data created!');
        var id = product._id;

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the product data with id: ' + id);
    });    
})
```

In the same way you can post the image using the product_id that will get as response when the product is added in mongodb. When you want to see the image to which it belongs then you can pass the product_id as parameter

```
app.get('/productImage/:productId',function(req,res,next){
Image.find({"product_id":req.params.productId}, function (err, data) {
    if(err) console.log("error");
    if(data==true){
        res.json(batch);
    }
    });
});
```

If you want any other information let me know. Hope this helps

Comment: ok, I'll try that approach.
Can you help me with uploading multiple images to server folder, & save imagePaths to mongoDb?

Comment: I searched a lot, but couldn't find any working solution to this.I got tutorials that will use modules like **multer**, but they will only save images to folder, but will not save imagePaths to mongoose collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already have one code snippet, it will post one imagePath to mongoDb, I need to fix that code, so that I can post multiplt imapePaths to image collection.I will share that code with you as well.

Comment: Sure update your post with it so that it will be helpfull to all

Comment: You want the path from where the file is uploaded or destination path at which the file is uploaded???

Comment: I want the destination path like this  `uploads/product/images/filename.jpg`in my **image collection** along with productId.

Comment: Is it okk with multer module

Comment: I am able to save image(s) to folder using multer, but couldn't store `imagePaths` to `image Collection`.

Comment: I want my **image collection** like this :
`{
"_id": "aerererwerwer009we",
"productId": "adfasd234234001",
"imagePaths": [{"uploads/product/images/file1.jpg"},
{"uploads/product/images/file2.jpg"},
{"uploads/product/images/file3.jpg"}
]
}`

Comment: Wait I will give you full  MEAN stack code I am working on it

Comment: okay sure, hopefully it will work, this thing is plaguing me for days.

Comment: You want to maintain two collection or one???I mean one collection for product and another collection for images

Comment: For now I want separate collections, i.e one for data & other one  for images.But only single collection will also work.

Comment: I have posted my MEAN stack code, please have a look.

Comment: Hello @mayank bisht I completed the task as per your requirement .But I am unable to add another image for product using productId in image schema.So I am working on it.Sorry for the late reply.If you are kk with one image for product Id I will answer your post you want to add more images for that product Id I will complete it and then I will post my answer.Let me know....

Comment: Hi @Syed Ayesha, oh okay, that's great. yes you can post that code, that will be really helpful.

Comment: I add another answer check it and let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: can you help me out with this thing? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217162/how-to-use-jimp-module-with-multer`