# Obtain Newly Created Object ID in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have the following MongoDB query and I am using the mongodb node.js driver to connect:

```
db.collection('employee').insertOne(employeeObj).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", err);
});
```

From the above, I would like to obtain the newly created employee's Object _Id but when I console log the result, I get:

```
Object { n: 1, ok: 1 }
```

Using the above query, how can I also include the new `_id` just created within the returned result?

Comment: Can you please log `console.log(result.ops[0]);` and let us know what it shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [result object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult) should contain a `insertedId` property which is driver generated `ObjectId` for the insert operation.

Try to log `result.insertedId` to check the id, and also you should have the inserted object in the `ops` property.

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field would be added to the `employeeObj` once it is added to the collection.

This is from the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne):

> **insertOne(doc, options, callback)** 
> Inserts a single document
>   into MongoDB. If documents passed in do not contain the _id field, one
>   will be added to each of the documents missing it by the driver,
>   mutating the document. This behavior can be overridden by setting the
>   forceServerObjectId flag.

Just change the code to:

```
db.collection('employee').insertOne(employee).then(result => {
    console.log(employee._id);
    res.send({employee, result});
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", err);
});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs) might be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using mongoose package. If you want to create custom _id for your document you can use

```
var newId = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId('56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca');
```

and pass it with your employee object.

more info go [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Types).

Comment: I don't think he's using mongoose!

Comment: @Sid - you are correct - I am not using mongoose. I am actually using the mongodb node.js driver - require('mongodb').MongoClient;