# How get last assigned objectID of collection

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

i have 2 collections one for store agent details like name and agent type..etc,and another one for storing user credentials details like user_name and password

```
agent_collection{
   _id:''
   NAME:'',
   MAIL:''
}
user collection{
_id:'',
agent_id:'',
user_name:'',
password:''
}
```

now i want `ObjectId` of `agent_collection` in  `user_collection` as value of `agent_id` while inserting new record.is there any methods available for getting ObjectId of collection

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the \_id of inserted document in Mongo database in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *insert* method has the form: [insertOne(doc, options, callback)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#insertOne)

The callback is of type [insertOneWriteOpCallback(error, result)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpCallback) where the `result` is a `insertOneWriteOpResult` object. The `result` object has a `insertedId` field; this is "The driver generated ObjectId for the insert operation.".

So, your code can be:

```
  let new_agent_doc = { agent_name: 'John Doe', email: 'johnd@example.com' }

  collection.insertOne(doc, (err, result) => {

      console.log('inserted the following ID: ', result.insertedId);
      // use the newly created agent's id value: result.insertedId
  });
```