# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in post method in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to nodejs and mongodb.
I am trying to create simple to-do app with nodejs and mongodb.
I have added the task in database.
Now in post method, I am using insertOne method of mongodb and in res.json I am having the following error.

res.json(info.ops[0].data)
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Code :

```
app.post('/create-item', function(req, res){
    db.collection('items').insertOne({ text:req.body.text }, function(err, info){
      res.json(info.ops[0])
    })
})
```

Below is the screenshot of Error. [image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current versions, there is no property returned named `ops` when `insertOne` is successful.

Hence the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

`insertOne` returns two properties:

> `acknowledged`
> Indicates whether this write result was acknowledged. If not, then all other members of this result will be undefined
> `insertedId`
> The identifier that was inserted. If the server generated the identifier, this value will be null as the driver does not have access to that data

See:

- [InsertOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#insertOne)
- [InsertOneResult](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/interfaces/InsertOneResult.html)

```js
app.post('/create-item', function(req, res){
    db.collection('items').insertOne({ text:req.body.text }, function(err, info){
      console.log(info.acknowledged)
       console.log(info.acknowledged)
      res.json(info.acknowledged)
    })
})
```

In previous versions, for example `3.2`, different properties were returned for `insertOne`:

- [insertOne @3.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne)
- [insertOneWriteOpCallback @3.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#%7EinsertOneWriteOpCallback)

Similarly, different properties were returned for `updateOne`:

- [updateOne @3.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne)
- [updateOneWriteOpCallback @3.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#%7EupdateWriteOpCallback)

For more information about migrating to version 4 from earlier versions, see the article:

[Changes in 4.x (and how to migrate!)](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne)

Comment: in case it helps anyone, i recently updated an old project that used to have `"mongodb": "^3.2.7"` as a dependency in `package.json`.  my code did reference `topic_id = topic.ops[0]._id.toString()`.  the mongodb node docs are currently at version `4.1`.  in the mongodb node article [Changes in 4.x (and how to migrate!)](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.1/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md), the [CRUD results](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.1/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md#crud-results) section specifically mentions the changes to the result properties of `insertOne()`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with the to-do app tutorial today. For those interested try changing the line - res.json(info.ops[0])

to - res.json({ _id: info.insertedId.toString(), text: req.body.text })

This gets the inserted id from the database for the newly added item. As "info" doesn't seem to return the inserted text in the current version of mongodb - i added that from the request parameter.

I got my information from here - [Get the _id of inserted document in Mongo database in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481521/get-the-id-of-inserted-document-in-mongo-database-in-nodejs/54204838#54204838)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you are doing it wrong way firstly check the err then send the res.json because the error is because your info might be null if data not inserted successfully so you need to do it like

```
app.post('/create-item', function(req, res){
    db.collection('items').insertOne({ text:req.body.text }, function(err, info){
      if (err) {
           res.json({message: "not inserted successFully"});
           return;
       }
      res.json(info.ops[0])
    })
})
```

now in above code what will happen if data is not inserted successfully it will send the error as response and return from function.

Comment: Still, The error remains there :( I have uploaded screenshot for reference.